# What's the path of runner - whenever - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I'm trying to execute a model with the 'runner' option and I don't seem to find the correct path.

My `cronjobs.rb` file in `/app/models/`:

```
class Cronjobs
  def tryCron
    notificacion = Notificacion.new

    notificacion.idNotificacion = '1'
    notificacion.idUser = '1'
    notificacion.notification_type = 'cron_job'
    notificacion.text ='cronojob'
    notificacion.href = 'cron'
    notificacion.state = 'done'
    notificacion.date_created = Time.zone.now.to_datetime - 3.hours
    notificacion.save
  end 
end
```

And here is my schedule.rb

```
set :output, 'log/cron.log'

every 5.minutes do
  runner "Cronjobs.tryCron"
end
```

And on the log it says that 'tryCron' its an undefined method of the class `Cronjobs:Class`

Comment: `runner 'Cronjobs.new.tryCron'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Cronjobs
  def self.tryCron
```

I think it should help, and by the way don't evere name methods in camelcase, use underscore try_cron

Comment: The 'self.' definition did the trick. Thank you very very much !

On the other side I've got plenty of 'rails apps' and for some reason it runs the Cronjobs.try_cron on another app... So it uses another DB. 

It may be cause I have 'wheneverized it' from another linux user.

I hope I made my new problem clear.

Any solutions ?

Thank you !!! Saved me ;)

Comment: Nevermind, solved it 

command 'bash -c 'source /home/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm && /usr/bin/env ruby /home/username/path/to/archive.rb method'